# Is there any better way to find GPS is enabled or not?

Tags: android, locationmanager, android-gps

I need to check GPS availability to fetch the current location. I'm using the below code to see whether GPS is ON or OFF.

```
LocationManager manager =
 (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
boolean location = manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

But the above code returns true even if the GPS is OFF. Code is working properly till Android 6.0, Is there anything has been changed after 6.0? (Nexus 5, lenovo and other marshmallow devices gave true value even though GPS was OFF).

Comment: have you take a look at this http://droidmentor.com/get-the-current-location-in-android/

Comment: Yes. I'm fetching the current location in similar way. But I need to make sure GPS is ON before launching the Map.